# how to attach socket.io to SwaggerExpress

Tags: node.js, swagger, middleware

I am using swaggerexpress middleware and swagger.
I can't get to work with socket.io
What is the proper way to attach socket.io to my server created?

```
'use strict';

var SwaggerExpress = require('swagger-express-mw');
var app = require('express')();
var io = require('./api/helpers/socketio');

module.exports = app;

var config = {
    appRoot: __dirname
};

SwaggerExpress.create(config, function(err, swaggerExpress) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    swaggerExpress.register(app);
    app.listen(10010, function () {
        console.log('Application is start listening on localhost:10010');
    });
     io.on('connection',function(socket){
     console.log("A user is connected: " + socket.id);
     io.emit('message', "Welcome")
    });

});
io.attach(app);
```

With that approach, my server is not getting up, got an error on socket.io attaching to app.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Is smb up to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay using a different port for socket.io, you could do something like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(10011);
// Or maybe in your case: 
// var io = require('./api/helpers/socketio')(10011);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('user connected');
});
```

On the client you'd connect to it like this:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:10011');

socket.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('Socket connection established');
});
```